# What is missing from my Tornado app to successfully use my own OpenID server

Tags: python, openid, tornado

I'm trying to build a website using the Tornado framework that is using OpenID to authenticate with an OpenID authentication service, also built using Tornado.

I've created a child class based on tornado.auth.OpenIdMixin and am using that as the authenticaton handler in my Tornado app:

```
class MyMixin(tornado.auth.OpenIdMixin):
    _OPENID_ENDPOINT = "http://myserver.com/openidserver"

    def authorize_redirect(self, oauth_scope, callback_uri=None, ax_attrs=["name", "email", "language", "username"]):
            callback_uri = callback_uri or self.request.uri
            args = self._openid_args(callback_uri, ax_attrs=ax_attrs)
            self.redirect(self._OPENID_ENDPOINT + "?" + urllib_parse.urlencode(args))

    def get_authenticated_user(self, callback):
            tornado.auth.OpenIdMixin.get_authenticated_user(self, callback)
```

The handler class for the application is

```
class AuthHandler(BaseHandler, MyMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
            if self.get_argument("openid.mode", None):
                    self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
                    return
            self.authenticate_redirect()

    def _on_auth(self, user):
            if not user:
                    self.send_error(500)
            self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user), expires_days=0.01)
            self.redirect("/")
```

This code is based on what the GoogleMixin class is doing and an example I found online at http://technobeans.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/tornado-third-party-authentication/

For the OpenID server I started with server.py from https://github.com/openid/python-openid but after running into some issues I also tried https://github.com/mrjj/cito. In both servers I have an account available for me to login to but both times I'm having the same problem on the client side.

My goal is to have my client see that I'm not logged in, redirect me to the OpenID server, I authenticate there, give the client permission to authenticate me using the ID and be redirected to the client to move on from there.

But with both servers my client always fails in AuthHandler._on_auth() because the user parameter is None.

This is the output of Tornado running my client:

```
ERROR:root:Exception after headers written  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 897, in wrapper  
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "website.py", line 67, in _on_auth  
    self.redirect("/")  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 412, in redirect  
    raise Exception("Cannot redirect after headers have been written")  
Exception: Cannot redirect after headers have been written
```

After adding some debugging `print` statements I know that the HTTP/500 error I'm getting is because the `user` variable is empty.

I know I don't quite understand how OpenID is supposed to work, but I can't find a practical example of how OpenID is supposed to work. There's a few diagrams with lots of arrows back and forth, but nothing with a little more technical detail.

All freely available servers I've looked at appear to be providing the same basic set of functions.

- Am I pointing to the correct URL for the authentication process to start?
- Am I missing some step in my clients' OpenID handling and it is looking too much like what Google is doing with their OpenID+OAuth protocol?

Comment: So I've just abandoned this route and just gave up with OpenID for the time being.